# <select> does not change its selected <option> when setting a default value

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am creating a select component with a default value through props but suddenly when i tried to select an option, select do nothing.

I tried not to put a initial value it solve the problem but the program should not act like that.

```
//UserMaintenanceModal
class UserMaintenanceModal extends Component {
    state = {
        user_department: this.props.data.user_department,
        departments: [
            {id: 1, name: "IT"}, {id:2, name: "BM"}
        ]
    }

    handleChange = (event) => {
        this.setState({user_department: event.target.value});
    }

    render(){
        const { user_department } = this.state;
        return (
            <label>Department</label>
            <select 
                className="form-control form-control-sm" 
                name='user_department'
                value={user_department}
                onChange={this.handleChange}
             >
             {
              this.state.departments != null && this.state.departments.map(
                       department => 
                           <option 
                               key = {department.id} 
                               value = {department.name}
                            >
                                {department.name}
                            </option>
                      )
               }
               </select>
        )
    }
}
```

**Solution**

Sorry, my mistake. I did not show all of the source code. The reason it was not changing it  because of this code which is inside a parent component.

```
//NavComponent

componentWillMount() {
    document.addEventListener('mousedown', this.handleClick, false);
}

componentWillUnmount() {
  document.removeEventListener('mousedown', this.handleClick, false);
}
```

I did get this code from [here](https://medium.com/@pitipatdop/little-neat-trick-to-capture-click-outside-react-component-5604830beb7f). It act to hide active dropdown nav menu when click outside of the component.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Take a look at this CodePen I've made: https://codepen.io/Gesma94/pen/QYYWKG

Since you are taking the value from the props, it means the parent Component keeps the value in the state (probably), so, when you select an option, you need to update the state of the parent Component, and in order to do that you need an handlerFunction passed to the Component with the options from the Parent.

```
class List extends React.Component {
    options = ["one", "two", "threee"];

    render() {
        const {handleChange, value} = this.props;
        return (
            <select value={value} onChange={handleChange}>
                {
                    this.options.map((option, index) =>
                        <option key={index} value={option}>
                            {option}
                        </option>
                 )}
            </select>
        );
    }
}

class App extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);

        this.state = {value: "one"};
    }

    handleChange = (e) => {
        this.setState({value: e.target.value})
    }

  render() {
      return <List handleChange={this.handleChange} value={this.state.value} />
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById("root"));
```

---

**EDIT** Ok, so.. One of the problem is what I said yesterday: you pass to the `UserMaintenanceModal` Component the default value, which is saved in the state of the `App` Component. But then, in `UserMaintenanceModal` Component you update the state of itself, and not the state of the `App` Component, so you kinda have an inconsistency.

Anyways, this is not your biggest problem: as far as I can see, there is some "confusion" (or maybe it's more probably that I don't fully understand what you want to achieve :) ). So, now I'm assuming that, as I said in the comment, you just want to display all the users belonging with the department selected!

I see that, inside the `handleChange` of `App` Component you save in the `data` property of the state the information about the currently clicked user (I don't know if this is mandatory or it was a try to achieve what I assumed). In case you did you want to save that info, that is redundant since you already have all these information in the `users` property: you could just save the `userId` or the position in the `users` array of the clicked user.

Then, I also don't understand why `showModal` is originally set to `false` and became `true` when  you click on a user: this way it seems all the users should be visible at start, and once you clicked on one of them you kinda filter the users by the Department to which the clicked user belongs with. But if this is the case, I don't know why the select should became visible after.. :S

Finally, in the `render()` method of the `App` Component you should somehow say "hei, render only the users that belongs with the department selected", which you did not attempt (as far as I can see). In the following example I'm using a `filter` native function, but you could just have kept only the `map` function and return the user only if its `user_department` was equal to the currently selected.

Anyways, I also assumed that the selection should be visible from start, and I've forked your codepen, take a look at this and let me know if this is what you wanted: https://codepen.io/Gesma94/pen/aXXjvE

Notice that, in this example, the departments values are in the state of `UserMaintenanceModal` which isn't a good thing at all: you should retrieve the departments from the `users` array saved in the state of the `App` Component, and then pass them to the `UserMaintenanceModal` Component.. I mean, you should do something like "ok, let's see all my users and see all the departments that I have.. Ok now, that I have it, let's pass them to the `UserMaintenanceModal`.

Comment: I made a second codepen because of your edit → https://codepen.io/Gesma94/pen/vbbYzE
Honestly, it works, so maybe there's an error somewhere else..? BTW, if you expect that the value `this.props.data.user_department` changes too when you change the state of `UserMaintenanceModal`, it won't happen: you have created a copy of that value inside the state of `UserMaintenanceModal`, so the value in the Parent Component won't change

Comment: I edited your work and that the exact code of my react app. It work on codepen but not on my project. Check this codepen.io/anon/pen/aXXdqz?editors=0011 and try creating a react app on your computer.

Comment: Can you explain me what is the purpose of your work? I can guess that you want to show only rows having the column `Department` equal to the value selected in the `select`. Am I right?

Comment: your right because it is not necessary to include other properties. this is to demo the error.

Comment: I've edited  the answer here above.. Take a look at it! :)

Comment: Sorry friend look like we have a big miss understanding. The program should list all the users then when i clicked a row it will show a modal with the user details. To be not a time consuming demo i only show department dropdown which should have a default value what ever in the props.data.user_department. I also use the && because when i put this.state.departments.map(...) early it will have an error same goes to app conponent this.state.users.map(...). I will upload the while project on github. Please stay tune. It a really wierd error.

Comment: I did finally got the solution.

Comment: I was waiting for the git repo, but great news! Glad you resolved and, if I did, that I helped! :)

Answer (score 1):

You can put the default value prop in the component state and continue to use that.

**Example**

```js
class App extends React.Component {
  state = {
    options: ["foo", "bar", "baz"],
    selectedOption: this.props.defaultOption
  };

  onChange = e => {
    this.setState({ selectedOption: e.target.value });
  };

  render() {
    const { options, selectedOption } = this.state;

    return (
      <select value={selectedOption} onChange={this.onChange}>
        {options.map((option, index) => (
          <option key={index} value={option}>
            {option}
          </option>
        ))}
      </select>
    );
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(<App defaultOption="bar" />, document.getElementById("root"));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>

<div id="root"></div>
```

Comment: i run the code snippet it work but when i did appy to my program it does not work.

Comment: @AdrianManuelCleofe That's frustrating. Could you update the question with your entire component?

Comment: @AdrianManuelCleofe [You could take the `id` of the default department and it will work well](https://codesandbox.io/s/wovzw4nzol).

Comment: It work on codepen but not on my project. Check this [link]https://codepen.io/anon/pen/aXXdqz?editors=0011

Answer (score 0):

Problem

In my case, I wanted to switch or render different components to fill based on the `selected` field. Whenever I switched it, I could not be able to reset the selected fields of the rendered component. as a result, I could not show the right placeholder rather first `option`. This wrong and could confuse users.

Solution

> I added the `defaultValue` in `select` tag.
> This the placeholder I want a user to see for the first time

> I added the `value` in `select` tag.
> This helped me to track whenever users changed the mind or clean the data.

```js
 <select
        name={inputName}
        id={inputId}
        className="input-controller-required"
        required
        onChange={onHandleInputChange}
        defaultValue={defaultValue}
        value={defaultValue}   // I forgot to add value
      >
        <option disabled value="">{placeholder}</option>
        {
          options.map((item, index) => (
            <option value={item.value} key={index}>{item.text}</option>
          ))
        }
      </select>
```

Thanks, @Jolly's answer and other contributors for support.